# Prevent radio button from being checked but cannot get RadioButton component object from ionSelect ion-radio

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to prevent the radio button from being checked if ionSelect function does not perform as I expected.

I cannot get the $event of ionSelect function of ion-radio tag as a RadioButton component so I can set the checked value to false if I want.

here is my code:

```
            <ion-list radio-group>
                <ion-item class="item-child">
                    <ion-label>Manual</ion-label>
                    <ion-radio item-start (ionSelect)="changeMode($event)" color="secondary"></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item class="item-child">
                    <ion-label>Auto</ion-label>
                    <ion-radio item-start (ionSelect)="changeMode($event)" color="secondary"></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
```

ts file:

```
import { RadioButton } from 'ionic-angular';

        public changeMode(event: RadioButton) {
            console.log(event);
    }
```

it logs like this `rb-11-0`

I updated the latest version of ionic-angular but it still happens.
I tried with

```
public changeMode(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
```

}
but still the same log result.

What is the problem ?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Mystery I think it must be an RadioButton object, with properties : checked, value, ...

Answer (score 1):

As per your requiremnets you need to pass value in your `changeMode` like below :

```
<ion-list radio-group>
        <ion-item class="item-child">
            <ion-label>Manual</ion-label>
            <ion-radio item-start (ionSelect)="changeMode('manual')" color="secondary"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-child">
            <ion-label>Auto</ion-label>
            <ion-radio item-start (ionSelect)="changeMode('auto')" color="secondary"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

**change your method :**

```
  public changeMode(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
  }
```

**log of your value :**

```
manual
auto
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: I want to prevent radio button from being checked if changeMode function doesn't perform as I expected (maybe if else inside this function). How can I do that ?

Comment: means you want to reset radio selection ?

Comment: I want to check a condition before the radio button be checked. If true, the radio button's checked and if false, it still remains unchecked. I don't wanna check it and then uncheck it. Is it possible ?

Comment: no you can not do like that as there is no action before change event fire while user click on check box. means first it will check/uncheck radio button and that event fire.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide me an answer that uncheck the radio button ? I think I can use this.

Comment: Because I can do that with checkbox (follow here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-do-i-prevent-an-ion-checkbox-from-being-checked/126731/3) so I think I can do it with radio button. Poor me